# Use RSQLite to manipulate data frame in r directly using SQL

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown, data-wrangling, rsqlite

I have a data set of the form
[image]

that I would like to change to this form below in R using SQL.
[image]

I know that I could do this daily simply with `dplyr` but the point here is to learn to use SQL to create and manipulate a small relational database.

- `Price` needs to be turned into a numeric value. Removing the "R" and spaces in between.
- `coordinates` needs to be turned into 2 coordinates `Long` and `Lat`
- `floor size` needs to be turned into a numeric from a string removing the space and "m^2" at the end.

***Minimum working example***

```
# Data to copy into sheet

       Price                            coordinates floor.size surburb       date
 R 1 750 000 -33.93082074573843, 18.857342125467635      68 m²     Jhb 2021-06-24
 R 1 250 000 -33.930077157927855, 18.85420954236195      56 m²     Jhb 2021-06-17
 R 2 520 000 -33.92954929205658, 18.857504799977896      62 m²     Jhb 2021-06-24
```

***Code to manipulate in R markdown***

````
```{r}
#install.packages("RSQLite", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(knitr)

db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(connection = "db")


# Import data
dataH <- read_excel("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/exampledata.xlsx")

``` 

```{sql, connection = db}
# SQL code passed directly
```
````

***Edit 1:***

The answer by @Onyambu works almost. It is producing an error with the coordinates. For example in the image below the last two coordinates are supposed to have a `Long` that starts with '18.85' instead of '.85' when the `coordinate` was "-33.930989501123, 18.857270308516927". How would I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html)? It allows SQL queries against a `data.frame`(s).

Comment: Please post your data using `dput(x)`, since as-is we cannot just copy and paste without a bit of manual extract. (The embedded spaces make it so that `read.table` and family cannot just parse it.)

Comment: Also you need to specificly state what db engine you are using. mysql, sqllite, postgresql etc all have different functions to be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the basic sql functions, you could do:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,connection = "db")
```

```{r}
db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

txt <- "Price coordinates floor.size surburb date\n
     'R 1 750 000' '-33.93082074573843, 18.857342125467635' '68 m²' Jhb 2021-06-24\n
     'R 1 250 000' '-33.930077157927855, 18.85420954236195' '56 m²' Jhb 2021-06-17\n
     'R 2 520 000' '-33.92954929205658, 18.857504799977896' '62 m²' Jhb 2021-06-24"

dataH <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE) 
DBI::dbWriteTable(db, 'dataH', dataH)
```


```{sql}
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(price, 3, 100), ' ', '') price,
       replace(SUBSTRING(coordinates, 1, 20), ',', '') Lat,
       SUBSTRING(coordinates, 21, 255) Long,
       SUBSTRING(`floor.size`, 1, 2) floor_size,
       surburb,
       date
FROM dataH
```
````

Comment: The actual data is much bigger than 4 rows and has more columns than those that I specified. Could this be written in such a way that I import the data as an R object and then perform the manipulations as I go along(manipulating columns)? @Onyambu

Comment: @user849541 i am not only using the 4 rows but everything. You need the SQL CODE. The R code was just for data replication. On your code, once you have imported the data as dataH, then do `dbWriteTable` as in my code above, followed by the sql code above

Comment: I am getting the following error:  Error in (function (sql, outputFile, options)  : 
  The 'connection' option (DBI connection) is required for sql chunks.

Comment: For last chunk, use: `{sql, connection = db}`

Comment: Hi @Onyambu, there is something that is giving issues with the coordinates. I added it into the question as an edit.

Comment: Perhaps @Parfait might know how to fix the issue with the coordinates transformation?

Comment: Could it be that the decimals are not the same length per say @Onyambu

Comment: @Parfait I placed `connection = db` within the setup chunck, so not really necessary to include it again, but no problem if included

Comment: @user849541 Since I do not know your database engine, there is really no way to use `REGEX` . If your engine supports regular expression, then you could use functions like `regexp_replace` etc

Comment: I am a bit confused by what you mean by this "REGEX"?

Comment: @user849541 REGEX simply means regular expressions. It can be used to extract patterns from a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charindex` and `substr` to do what you need. I'll demo with `sqldf`, which is using SQLite's engine under the hood. (This query is very similar to Onyambu's but solves one issue with text selection.)

```r
dat <- structure(list(Price = c("R 1 750 000", "R 1 250 000", "R 2 520 000"), coordinates = c("-33.93082074573843, 18.857342125467635", "-33.930077157927855, 18.85420954236195", "-33.92954929205658, 18.857504799977896"), floor.size = c("68 m²", "56 m²", "62 m²"), surburb = c("Jhb", "Jhb", "Jhb"), date = c("2021-06-24", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-24")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

out <- sqldf::sqldf(
  "select cast(replace(substr(price,2,99),' ','') as real) as price,
          cast(substr(coordinates,1,charindex(',',coordinates)-1) as real) as lat,
          cast(substr(coordinates,charindex(',',coordinates)+1,99) as real) as long,
          cast(substr([floor.size],1,charindex('m',[floor.size])-1) as real) as [floor.size]
   from dat", method = "raw")

out
#     price       lat     long floor.size
# 1 1750000 -33.93082 18.85734         68
# 2 1250000 -33.93008 18.85421         56
# 3 2520000 -33.92955 18.85750         62

str(out)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ price     : num  1750000 1250000 2520000
#  $ lat       : num  -33.9 -33.9 -33.9
#  $ long      : num  18.9 18.9 18.9
#  $ floor.size: num  68 56 62
```

(The number of digits shown in the `out` output is due to R's `"digits"` option, those are class `numeric` as shown in the `str` output.)

You can shorten that and remove all `cast(.. as ..)` if you change to `sqldf(.., method="numeric")`.

```r
out <- sqldf::sqldf(
  "select replace(substr(price,2,99),' ','') as price,
          substr(coordinates,1,charindex(',',coordinates)-1) as lat,
          substr(coordinates,charindex(',',coordinates)+1,99) as long,
          substr([floor.size],1,charindex('m',[floor.size])-1) as [floor.size]
   from dat", method = "numeric")
```